# Create audio spectrum visualizer android app

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make like a audio spectrum visualizer something like this:

[image]

I already have the AAC player that connects to an audio stream and plays the music. How can I now add this visualization component?

Comment: https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer may help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean by audio spectrum the frequency spectrum you could take these steps:

- Convert the audio data to a raw audio format like 16-Bit PCM (maybe in windows if you use a stream)
- Use a Fast Fourier Transformation library like JTransforms to calculate the frequency spectrum over your window.
- Visualize the array which contains the values from the spectrum

Comment: but i cannot use some component in android to achieve this more easly? i mean without convert audio? because is a live stream u know what i mean? thanks very much

Comment: my player already plays raw aac stream from an shoutcast url

Comment: I haven´t tried it with that format, maybe it works without the conversion step.

Comment: If you compute the frequency spectrum you might also get a little bit of delay. If it is just for eye candy I would choose something else that is faster.

Comment: what u recommend me ? which method , thanks

Comment: Maybe take the windows and compute the power(the squared signal value) and then take for the first bar in your pic the average of the first 10 power values and for the second bar the next 10 etc. And then jump with the window to the next data and do it again. You definitely need windows anyways, so you could first try it like that, and if it doesnt look good you can still compute the frequencies and see if it is fast enough.

Comment: thanks bro, ill appreciate that will help me alot im going to start working on this.

Comment: @alexistkd did you succeeded to achieve this visualizer for your android app..please help me